# Volume of bounded region

Tags: volume

I  would like to find the volume of the region bounded by:

$x^2 + y^2 = 1$

I just need help setting up the integral. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

My work thus far:

$V = \int_0^{2 \pi} \int _0 ^1 \int _ {r^2(1+2sin2 \theta)} ^ {4-r^2(1+2sin2 \theta)}rdzdrd \theta$

Comment: Can you please include your work on the set up?

Comment: I added my work thus far.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  I've rollbacked your [edit].  Please don't deface your own post so that others (e.g. @Shailesh from [LQ review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1002346)) understand your question and your attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find the intersection of the the two surfaces, to find $$ x^2+y^2 =1.$$

Then set up the integral in cylindrical coordinates.

$$ V= \int _0^{2\pi} \int _0^1 \int _{r^2(1+2\cos ^2 \theta)} ^{4-r^2(1+2\sin ^2 \theta)}  dzr dr d \theta $$

Comment: For the inner-most integral, how did you get those limits of integration?

Comment: The lower limit is the lower surface in polar form and the upper limit is the upper surface in polar form. $( x=r\cos \theta ,  y=r\sin \theta)$

Comment: $ \sin^2 \theta + \cos ^2 \theta =1$

Comment: The correct answer is $2\pi$ and both methods give the same correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I need to improve my integration skills - obviously! I hope you have a great weekend.

Comment: Thanks and  have a good one.